# Tensorflow: how to load a ".npy" file to a net

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to load "vgg16.npy" to a vggnet written by myself.
I wonder if you could help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: I think you should give more info about your problem. Why do you not initialize weights by data loaded from file, when you create `tf.Variable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy the weights/biases of your `.npy` file directly to your network, as they will be considered as constants. Therefore, first you need to initialize a `tf.Variable`:

```
conv1_weights = tf.get_variable('conv1_weights', initializer=data['conv1']['weights'])

conv1_biases = tf.get_variable('conv1_biases', initializer=data['conv1']['biases'])
```

This is a real example from my code. *data* is an object created by the *np.load* function.

---

Then, to add it to your network:

```
conv_kernel_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, **conv1_weights**, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID', name='conv1')

bias_layer_1 = relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv_kernel_1, conv1_biases))
```

I hope the example is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for converting 'static' length of npy file to a tensor.
1. Use tf.read_file() to get raw string
2. according https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/npy-format.html, you can extra value from raw string, using tf.substr()
3. Use tf.py_func and struct.unpack to convert binary raw string to tf.float64

Hope this can help you. :)